# Does SUM work in Views

Tags: drupal-7, sum, drupal-views

I want use SUM in a views query but when I look at the generated query I don't see SUM anywhere. Do you have any idea if SUM should work?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Views php](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) module , this module provide for you a global php field(or filter) that can done what you want, some variable avaible there like $row, $views  ...,

Sometimes views  not provide my requires , I use this module to achieve my custom needs.
(for more information about it read `README.TXT` in module)

also you can use [omputed_field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module. this is another great module for computed field

Comment: As this is not my project now I see I'm trying to SUM Computed field. Seems it'll be much harder then i thought :\

Comment: Do u have idea how to subtraction date fields - rows with Views PHP

Comment: @Martin, yes I can, pelease put a screenshot of your views.

Comment: I'd like to get the same in the php col as the duration col(because VIEWS wouldn't SUM computed fields). Also if u have any idea how to exclude node.created from GROUP BY. I started a module using hook_views_pre_execute(&$view)

Comment: @Martin . not differenct how you use views, you should to add php field and in it calculate SUM

Comment: @Martin ,I see your views picture, which of fields you want calculate sum of them?